# Изменение стиля элемента при прокрутке страницы

Tags: html, javascript

есть [страница](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqF6c.jpg). При прокрутке до STICKY START нужно изменить стиль BLOCK #1. При прокрутке до STICKY END - изменить еще раз.

подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто в качестве примера:

```
window.onload = function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    window.scrollTo(0, 400);
                    $('div').css('color', 'red');
                }, 2000);
                setInterval(function() {
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    $('div').css('color', 'teal');
                }, 4000);
        }
```

Если надо что-то покруче ;-), то можно глянуть [тут](http://webdesignledger.com/tools/6-jquery-plugins-for-scrolling-effects) и [тут](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/scroll/)